# Extend jQuery to make placeholder like i have created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a placeholder around an `<input>` field:

HTML:

```
 <div style="position: relative;font-size: 20px;">
     <input type="text" name="username" id="lgip" style="width: 100%"  class="lgip"    value="<?php echo $username ?>" onkeyup="perform(this.value,'plcun')"/>
     <div class="placer" style="padding: 5px" onclick="$('#lgip').focus()" id="plcun">Enter UserName or Email Address</div>
 </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function perform(val,hid){
    if(val=="") {
        $("#"+hid).show();
    } else{
        $("#"+hid).hide();
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
input.lgip{ padding: 5px;font-size: 20px;border: 1px solid #2B4EA2 }
div.placer{ position: absolute;z-index: 5;top: 0px;left: 0px;background: transparent;width: 100%;color: #cccccc;white-space: nowrap;padding: 2px;padding-left: 4px }
```

Currently this requires me to add an outher `<div>` around the `<input>` and another `<div>` below it.

I want to extend jQuery so it can make a placeholder for any `input:text` and `textarea`, so that when I use something like `$("#lgip").makePlacer("Enter Username Or Email");` it will make a placeholder like the one I created.

Comment: **What is the question?** The jQuery documentation has a page on [how to write plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but I would recommend checking out the [Webshims Lib](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html). It provides support for the placeholder attribute in browsers that don't support it, as well as supporting the new HTML5 input types (email, date, number, etc) and HTML5 validation attributes (required, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing jQuery plugins is actually quite easy. Basically you just add your plugin function to the `jQuery.fn` object. In the plugin you can create the desired HTML elements and add them to the DOM.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.makePlacer = function(text){
        this.each(function(){
            var e = $(this);
            if (e.is("input[type='text'], textarea")) {
                var wrapper = $("<div/>").css({position: "relative", fontSize: 20});
                var placer = $("<div/>").html(text != undefined ? text : "").css({padding: 5}).addClass("placer").click(function(){
                    e.focus();
                });
                e.wrap(wrapper);
                e.after(placer);
                e.keyup(function(){
                    e.val().length ? e.next().hide() : e.next().show();
                });
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$("#lgip").makePlacer("Enter Username Or Email");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QQdfQ/1/